# bootstrap table first load not showing properly

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

bootstrap table not showing properyly when request data from server with jquery ajax but table showing first image after showing second image

```js
 var rows = $.parseJSON('[' + jsonstring_from_server + ']');
   
    $("#table").bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
        data: rows,
        pageSize: 100        
    });
```

why show table like first image

[image]

[image]